# Mysql. Limit $x1, $x2. Is it possible to do Limit $x2, $x1?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, $x1 = 10, $x2 = 25 then it will work Limit $x1, $x2. But I want to make Limit $x2, $x1 and it doesn't work. I want to get from newest to oldest entry from that list. ORDER BY doesn't work

**edited** you can close it, I've figured out by myself. I use

ORDER BY a_time DESC LIMIT $x2-$x1

now, so thanks.

Comment: How many rows are in the list? What's your schema and query? Does the query error or just not return any results? Can you give more info?

Comment: It doesn't give me any error, it gives a list, but not the from the newest to oldest.

Comment: @Tomas: You can delete the question - there's no impact to your reputation.  The delete link is next to the edit/flag links, found to the left of your username & icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the first 10 rows...

```
SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

To select the last 10 rows....

```
SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

This tells the script to start at 0, then count 10 rows.  This is the best/most efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just ORDER BY key DESC;

Then get end of the list. $count-$x2